# Developer console does not shows older version of apk

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

In Google Play developer console I had uploaded 10(ten) versions of my Application.
But it shows only Last three versions of applications.

Is this possible to show older release version in developer console??

**Is there any Criteria to display apk on google play developer console.?**

Thank You.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to play console -> Release Management -> Artifact Library -> Archived artifacts

Comment: I Found All Versions :) +1

Comment: We can see the versions but we can not deactivate the older versions.

Comment: What do you mean deactivate the old version? If there is a new version in release management then the archived artifacts are already deactivated

Comment: When releasing new version, we are able to deactivate the currently active version in the NEW Google play console.
But we had uploded older versions in erliar google play console . these versions were not deactivated in older google play console.
So the older Android devices with supports API below 16 can download these older versions of APK.

Answer (score 3):

HI JJG please see below image google change step

Follow this step-:

1 - Login

2-  All Application > select your application

3-  On left side select Release Management > App release > Manage Production > then Release History

[image: See this image follow those step]

Comment: Also you can follow archLucifer answer